# Play Framework - routes with default query param if one doesn't exist

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.4

I want to have a route like so:

```
GET  /login  com.me.controllers.Login(returnurl: String)
```

But I want `http://127.0.0.1:9000/login` to be a valid route which defaults to `http://127.0.0.1:9000/login?returnurl=%2F` ie the index page.

I could do this with a redirect (I've got a custom redirect controller), but just wondering if there is a cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the syntax that allows specifying [default parameters](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaRouting#Parameters-with-default-values).
For ex. you can do something like:

```
GET  /login  com.me.controllers.Login(returnurl: String ?= "/")
```

in your `routes` file.